# Check if users in CSV file are a part of 2 AD Groups or not. Both AD Groups have more than 5000 members

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

```
$userlist = get-content -Path "C:\users\Administrator\Downloads\users.txt"

 $group = "Fun-O365-EXO"

 Write-Host Following Users are not part of Fun-O365-EXO`
 $result = foreach ($user in $userlist)
{
    $groupmembers = Get-ADgroup -Filter {Name -eq $group} | Get-ADGroupMember

    if ($groupmembers.samaccountname -notmatch $user){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
       Name = $user 
        Group = $group 
        #Member = 'False'
        }
   }
    
}

$result
```

Unable to get required output in prod server maybe coz it has more than 5k members.

I have a txt file with multiple user ID in it. I need to know if they are a member of 2 AD Groups.

Comment: Use a hashtable for [Looking up entries by property in large collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#looking-up-entries-by-property-in-large-collections)

Comment: you mention 2 groups in your question but in your code I only see one. also, you don't need to get the group membership to know if a user is member of it

Answer (score 1):

You mention 2 groups in your question but in your code I only see one. Also, you don't need to get the group membership to know if a user is member of it, you know this via query.

```bash
$group1 = (Get-ADGroup Group1).DistinguishedName
$group2 = (Get-ADGroup Group2).DistinguishedName
$filter = "(&(memberOf=$group1)(memberOf=$group2)(samAccountName={0}))"

Get-Content -Path "C:\users\Administrator\Downloads\users.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $ldapFilter = $filter -f $_
    if(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter) {
        # here is for the user was a member of both groups
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Of cause, it is even better to filter remotely.